# How do you search for the status of current legal proceedings?

Tags: case-law, court-records

I'm curious about the case of Tristan Rettke, who was charged with civil rights intimidation for toting a confederate flag bag of bananas while wearing a gorilla mask at a BLM protest in 2016. The last status I could find via Google was [this link where his attorneys sought to dismiss the charges.](http://wjhl.com/2017/07/31/attorney-seeks-to-dismiss-charges-against-former-etsu-student-accused-of-civil-rights-intimidation/)

It seems like it was a long time ago and I'd like to know where the case stands. Is there a way to look up the county/state/federal records and find out?

Comment: I'd like to see a transcript of the trial myself. But he was more than likely found not guilty, considering the utter silence since about July.

Comment: Or they just didn't get around to ruling yet.  Courts are slow.

Comment: Three weeks ago, there had not yet been a trial, as implied by this article:http://www.johnsoncitypress.com/Education/2017/11/07/Noland-issues-statement-about-racist-campus-flyers-ahead-of-Black-Lives-Matter-founder-s-speech

Comment: @user6726: Or they just didn't find the records either. :)  There was supposed to be a hearing September 22 on some motions related to the case. But i've seen nothing definitive online dated past July 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like his case is/was in the Washington County TN court system.

According to their [website](http://www.washingtoncountytn.org/law_justice/criminal/docket), "To check the status of an upcoming Criminal Court case, please contact the clerk at 423-753-1612."  I don't see any way to get this information online.

Comment: Called the number. Nothing happened with the motion to dismiss this summer according to the operator. In September there was a motion to continue. Next day in court for the case is January 29th.